# VBA - Populate column based on value on another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I apologize if this is not the right place to ask this. However, I am a bit lost as to whom I should ask assistance. I know that what I want to accomplish can be done using the =IF formula. However, I would like to see if there is a VBA equivalent.

Below is a drive link to an spreadsheet (Copy of Concur AX Upload) and a CSV (Concur Extract).

In theory, I would like column I, in the worksheet titled "Copy of Concur AX Upload", to populate with "LLC" if column F in "Concur Extract" has "Department" in it. If column F in "Concur Extract" has "Property" in it, then I would like column I, in the worksheet titled "Copy of Concur AX Upload" to populate with the value already given in column G in "Concur Extract". I am sorry if it is unclear!
Thank you!!!!

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NGFdkydLx7gXwLFBpp5bKiZOSsPTqBN1

Comment: Please don't link to a spreadsheet, [edit] to embed the code in the post instead! See [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I write this following code based on both workbook. It's work fine for me.
Please adjust the path of workbook *Concur Extract 20180614.csv* :

```
Sub test()

'Adapt this path
Dim path_wb_csv As String
path_wb_csv = "C:\test\Concur Extract 20180614.csv"

'Define the workbook
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wb_csv As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wb_csv = Workbooks.Open(path_wb_csv)

'define the sheets that we use
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws_csv As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Expense JE")
Set ws_csv = wb_csv.Sheets("Concur Extract 20180614")


'define le last row
'adapt the column letter to define each last row of work book - I use column A
Dim wb_lastRow As Long
wb_lastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

For i = 2 To wb_lastRow Step 1


    If ws_csv.Cells(i, 6).Value = "Department" Then

        ws.Cells(i, 9).Value = "LLC"

    ElseIf ws_csv.Cells(i, 6).Value = "Property" Then

        ws.Cells(i, 9).Value = ws_csv.Cells(i, 7).Value

    End If

Next i


wb_csv.Close

End Sub
```